# Sequence with no __iter__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence, iterable

Is there any built-in type in Python 3 which implements `__getitem__` but does not implement the `__iter__` method?

I think in Python 2 the `str` type was this case but now in Python 3, str type has an `__iter__` method.

Comment: In python 3.9`memoryview`, none in 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html) seems to be the only one:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> [b for b in dir(builtins) 
     if isinstance(t := getattr(builtins, b), type) 
        and hasattr(t, '__getitem__') 
        and not hasattr(t, '__iter__')]
['memoryview']
```

There might be some standard modules that aren't loaded by default that have types like this.